# how to distribute .so file generated from cython

Tags: cython

I have been able to create a .so file on linux using cython on my .pyx script. I can also successfully do an import on my python interpretor.

My question is how do I get this .so installed on the end user's machine without using cython? I don't want to distribute any .pyx or .py or .c file to the end user. And also I don't want the end user to install cython or anything to use my .so file

Comment: I guess you'll have to make sure the end user has at least the same processor architecture. I'm not sure about inter-compatibility between different python versions though... Why not supply the user with a single .c file?

Comment: I don't want to give them the source. :)

Comment: Then it is a dead hand : you'll have to compile yourself for all targeted platforms...

Answer (score 3):

You can use `ldd` to check the static dependencies of your .so.  Here are the dependencies of a .so I built with cython on my Ubuntu desktop:

```
$ ldd iksolver.so 
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffc07fe000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fdcabc08000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fdcab903000)
libpython2.7.so.1.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0 (0x00007fdcab3d3000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fdcab00b000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fdcac068000)
libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007fdcaadf4000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fdcaabef000)
libutil.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libutil.so.1 (0x00007fdcaa9ec000)
$
```

You can see that it depends on many other libraries installed, and that it requires that python2.7 be installed, but everything here is installed in a default Ubuntu deployment.  Note that nothing here requires that Cython be installed.

You will be able to copy the .so to `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` on your destination machine, and you will then be able to import it, provided the same processor architecture and same version of the operating system are used.

Of course, if you have any `import` statements in your Cython module, you will need to ensure that those modules are also present on the destination system.

Comment: But I have read that copying directly the file to the directory is not a good practice. How can we do that with setup/distutils and/or pip ? I haven't seen anywhere example of that. Thx. D.

Answer (score 2):

It is easier and best to distribute a python wheel.
You will need pip3 on your target machine, but not Cython.

**On the building machine :**

Build your wheel with this kind of setup.py :

```
from Cython.Build import cythonize
from setuptools import setup, Extension

setup(  name='myPackage',
        version='1.0',
        py_modules=['myPackage'],
        ext_modules =
            cythonize(Extension("myPackageExtension",
                        # the extension name
                sources=["myPackageExtension.pyx", "Tool1.cpp", "Tool2.cpp"],
                        # the Cython source and additional C++ source files
                language="c++", # generate and compile C++ code
                                )
                        )
    )
```

And the followed command line :

```
python3 setup.py bdist_wheel
```

You will obtain a `.whl` file in `dist` folder.

**On the target machine :**

Copy the wheel file to your target machine
then install it with followed command line :

```
pip3 install myPackage-*-cp34-cp34m-linux_x86_64.whl
```

(note that your package is build for a version of python (cp34) and a dedicated platform (linux_x86_64), so you need to have same as building machine (or you can use [manylinux](https://github.com/pypa/manylinux) to solve this problem)).