# How to user-friendly distribute Cython .so?

Tags: python, cython

I use Linux to generate .so libraries for use in my Python-project. These libraries are dynamically linked, as also was stated in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14841535/how-to-distribute-so-file-generated-from-cython).

This requires recompilation on the users machine, if he does not use the same OS as I do. So my question is, how can I simplify this? I think I need to get Cython to statically link my library, but all I found on the web for this didn't work.

I use python-distutils to generate the .so. So a distutils solution would be nice, but any other suggestion will also help. I use this script:

```
cmdclass = {}
ext_modules = []

ext_modules += [
        Extension("signalFunctions", ["signalFunctions.pyx"],
                  include_dirs=[numpy.get_include()],
                  extra_compile_args=["-static", "-static-libgcc"]),
    ]
    cmdclass.update({'build_ext': build_ext})


setup(
    name='AutomaticHacker',
    cmdclass=cmdclass,
    ext_modules=ext_modules,
)
```

I already tried `extra_link_args=["fPIC"]` and `extra_link_args=["-static" "-static-libgcc"]` which did not work.

Comment: Why are you trying to statically link your library? It's still not going to work for someone who doesn't use the same OS as you do. Plus, if you want to be able to `import` something from Python, it still has to be a `.so`, even if it's statically linked all of its dependencies.

Comment: If you just want to not require Cython as a build requirement (so the user will only need Python and a C compiler), I believe you can cython-compile the .pyx files to .c files and distribute those. But I don't think I've ever seen a project that does that.

Comment: Thanks. I know, that I also can distribute a .c-File for the user to compile it. However, I want to distribute a kind of stand alone application where the only requirement is an installed python environment.

Comment: Well, you can't do that. The C code has to be linked against their Python build. If they have a different OS, or even a differently-built libpython, there's no binary you can give them that will work. (You _can_ build a complete bundled-up application that doesn't even require a Python build and only depends on a particular minimum LSB/Windows/OS X/etc. version, but that's a whole different thing.)

Comment: That sound's very interesting abarnert. Can you give me a link to a tutorial or something similar for this?

Comment: There are a number of projects like [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/). SO isn't a good place for ask for recommendations for one or another of them, or for tutorials ([SoftwareRecs](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com) might be, but don't quite me on that; read their help first…). But they all do similar things: build a self-contained directory, or even a single executable, out of your app. You still need to do it once on each OS, but then it should run on any linux with that LSB or later, any OS X that version or later, etc.

Comment: Another common thing to do is to supply DEB, RPM, etc. build scripts, build the ones you can and distribute those (and ideally get them upstream in the distro's main repo), and encourage your users to take care of any repos you can't. (You still need to deal with Mac and Windows, however.)